# Factor replacement converts to character in R

Tags: r, sapply

I want to replace the NA's in the selected columns to the last value in the levels of the column, but it keeps converting the column to character:

```
table(sapply(cop2014, class))

factor   numeric
400      116

varToCat = c("V21A","A3","Escolari","A17","B8","C5B","RamaEmpPri","C11","C16B",
         "C16C","D4B","D4C","RamaEmpSec","RamaUltEmpCesant","G12",
         "RamaFuerzaTrab","OcupFuerzaTrab","ActNoMer")

cop2014[,varToCat] = sapply(cop2014[,varToCat], 
        function(col) replace(col, is.na(col), last(levels(col))))
```

When I take a look at the classes of my variables I can see they changed.

`table(sapply(cop2014, class))`

```
character   factor   numeric
18          382      116
```

Any hint on why this is happening? I only want to replace the NAs with a valid factor (in this case is the last one on the levels)

Comment: use `lapply` instead of `sapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a case of conversion to `matrix` with `sapply` and a `matrix` can hold only a single class.  So, instead of `sapply`, use `lapply`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), last(levels(x))))
str(df1)
#'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ v1: Factor w/ 3 levels "B","D","E": 1 1 3 2 2 3 1 3 3 1
#$ v2: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 4 3 5 5 2 5 2 1 4 1
```

---

If we look at the output of `sapply`, it is a `matrix` and it can hold only a single class.  During the conversion to `matrix`, the attributes of `factor` are lost and it gets converted to `character`

```
sapply(df1, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), last(levels(x))))
#      v1  v2 
# [1,] "B" "D"
# [2,] "B" "C"
# [3,] "E" "E"
# [4,] "D" "E"
# [5,] "D" "B"
# [6,] "E" "E"
# [7,] "B" "B"
# [8,] "E" "A"
# [9,] "E" "D"
#[10,] "B" "A"
```

---

In addition to `lapply`, we can also use `mutate_at` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)  
cop2014 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(varToCat), funs(replace(., is.na(.), last(levels(.)))))
```

#### data

```
f1 <- function(n) sample(c(LETTERS[1:5], NA), n, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = f1(10), v2 = f1(10))
```